# Cakephp how to browse file?

Tags: php, cakephp

my question is how to get the content of a file from a input file
becausethe only thing im getting is the name of the file not the 
full path of the file.

```
    $handle = file_get_contents($this->data['btnBrowse']);
    $absolute = basename($this->data['btnBrowse']);
    var_dump($handle);
    var_dump($absolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$file = new File($dir);
$contents = $file->read();
$file->close();
```